# define bash aliases for Aquamacs shell

Tags: macos, emacs, aquamacs

for Emacs you can define your shell-mode aliases in .emacs.d/init_bash.sh, but Aquamacs (2.0 on OS X 10.5) does not seem to use this. Is there another place where these can be defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From shell.el:

> If a file `~/.emacs_SHELLNAME' exists,
>   or`~/.emacs.d/init_SHELLNAME.sh', it
>   is given as initial input (but this
>   may be lost, due to a timing error, if
>   the shell discards input when it
>   starts up). The buffer is put in Shell
>   mode, giving commands for sending
>   input and controlling the subjobs of
>   the shell.  See `shell-mode'. See also
>   the variable`shell-prompt-pattern'.

So you might want to try seeing whether **~/.emacs_bash** works.

Comment: Wow...that actually worked! But from that description there's no reason to suspect ~/.emacs.d/init_bash.sh wouldn't work. But I just created a link to that file (as .emacs_bash). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Solved for me:  I made two changes that seem to do the trick (I had earlier done Aquamacs -> Tools -> Install Command Line Tools).  The changes were: a) Remove the '~/.emacs_bash' symlink I'd created; b) Create a '~/.bashrc' file containing an invocation of my alias-setting script; c) Invoke '~/.bashrc' from '~/.bash_profile' (leaving exported env vars in ~/'.bash_profile' where they belong).

Aquamacs seems to append '/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/texbin' to the path it gets from '~/.bash_profile', but that doesn't seem to be a problem.

- - - My previous answer and question:

A symlink from '~/.emacs_bash' to '~/.bash_profile' succeeded in getting '~/.bash_profile' to execute on Aquamacs, so that the shell buffers have some of the desired settings (aliases).

However, what is needed is to configure Aquamacs so that '~/.bash_profile' executes once per Aquamacs session, and '~/.bashrc' executes once per Aquamacs shell?  Otherwise, for example with a link from '~/.emacs_bash' to '~/.bash_profile', concatenated shell variables (commonly, $PATH) get a lot of redundant values in them.

On *nix and Cygwin on NT, GNU Emacs works out of the box with '.bash_profile' and '.bashrc' in the expected way: '.bash_profile' is executed once on the *nix system, and all shells, including Emacs shell buffers, get the variables from that.  Likewise, '.bashrc' executes once per *nix shell, including for Emacs shell buffers.

Does anyone have any pointers to how to get Aquamacs to do the same?

Comment: you may want to post this as your own separate question with a link to this one? Might get more answers (I do not know).